# NMS Mojang Mappings

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, spigot

I am developing a server plugin in 1.17.1 and trying to use NMS I ran buildtools.jar and even after am still getting errors.

WORKS(without mojang mappings)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

DOES NOT WORK (Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot:jar:remapped-mojang:1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT in spigotmc-repo (https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/))

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>remapped-mojang</classifier>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried rerunning buildtools and stil got the issues.

I tried running buildtools with --remapped tag and still got same issue.

I tried right-clicking in my ide(Intellij) on the dependency and clicking download sources to the same issue.

Comment: Did you well run for 1.17**.1** ? Also, can you check it's well on your local repo at `~/.m2` ?

Comment: I checked ~,/.m2 and the file is there